# bootstrap 4 collapse (accordion table) in django

Tags: django, django-templates, bootstrap-4

I've posted the code for a table in django templates that is generated dynamically using an array from views.py. I've added a bootstrap4 collapse, that runs when a chevron button is clicked. However, it shows ALL of the hidden collapses instead of just the collapsible data for that given row (see img below).

I know that I can set ids dynamically, but I haven't had any luck passing functions to the "data-target" attribute.

[image: EXAMPLE]

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:5%"></th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <div class="container" id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            {% for r in result %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#demo" onclick="">
                        </button>
                    </td>

                    <td> {{ r.split.0 }}  </td> <!-- sample word -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.2 }}</td> <!-- ref word -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.4 }}</td> <!-- cost -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.3 }}</td> <!-- sum -->
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="demo" class="collapse" colspan="5" >

                        <!-- COLLAPSE CONTENT -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Reading closely the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#multiple-targets) should help you to generate the correct value in `data-target` attribute of your buttons, corresponding to the correct value for `id` or `class` attribute in your collapsible element tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "toogle button" have this HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#demo">
```

and the collapsible content is the following:

```
<td id="demo" class="collapse">[...]</td>
```

It's normal every toggle button show or hide all collapsible contents in your page, because all these elements are related to the same `#demo` identifier.

You have to make sure the id of collapsible content is unique accross all the document, and ensure the corresponding button references the same unique id. Maybe use your result id (from context variable) to do something like that:

```
<button type="button" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#demo-{{ r.pk }}">

<td id="demo-{{ r.pk }}" class="collapse">[...]</td>
```

**EDIT:** Of course, you have to adapt it to YOUR data. In this example, I imagine your list `result` contain many model instances, so in each result `r`, the value `r.pk` is unique.
In your template, if `results` contain something else, you have to make sure a unique str or int is extracted from each value to uniquify the `id`you write into your HTML.

Maybe it will be `demo-{{ r.split.6 }}` or `demo-{{ r.a_unique_attr_in_my_object }}` or `demo-{{ r.slugify }}`.

Comment: thank you... unfortunately it's still collapsing everything at the same time

Comment: did you check the generated html produced unique ids ? Something like `demo-2`, `demo-14`,  `demo-20`, etc ?

Comment: I never thought about that, cheers... I just checked and it's not generating new tags. When given 2 values, it produces two <td> cells with an identical id="demo-".

Comment: So, you have to update my example to adapt it to YOUR data. See the edit in my answer

Comment: ok cool, result is an array of variables with each index of the split representing the column that the data should go into. I tried using {{forloop.counter]} as the id, and it appears to work according to the source. But it does not function when the buttons are pressed.

Comment: Yeah, using `data-target="#demo-{{ forloop.counter }}"` and `<td id="demo-{{ forloop.counter }}">` is a good idea. And it should works well. Can you explain a bit more why it does not work ? Did you check what values are printed in HTML code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the content you want to hide under the  " COLLAPSE CONTENT ".

like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:5%"></th>
        <th>Sample</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Sum</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <div class="container" id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
            {% for r in result %}
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="fa fa-chevron-right rotate" data-toggle="collapse"
                                data-target="#demo" onclick="">
                        </button>
                    </td>


                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="demo" class="collapse" colspan="5" >

                     <td> {{ r.split.0 }}  </td> <!-- sample word -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.2 }}</td> <!-- ref word -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.4 }}</td> <!-- cost -->
                    <td> {{ r.split.3 }}</td> <!-- sum -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

By the way, don't forget the Bootstrap CDN

Comment: thanks, that's not working. I have included the CDN. My dilemma is that the collapse works but collapses/uncollapses all items at the same time.

Comment: the first row element contains the chevron button followed by my data, then the second row element contains the row element for the collapse.